# I got this 'TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'CartItems' and 'int' ' error while i am trying to add items to the cart

Tags: python, django

Views.py:

```py
def add_to_cart(request, product_id):
    product = Product.objects.get(id=product_id)
    try:
        cart = Cart.objects.get(cart_id=_cart_id(request))

    except Cart.DoesNotExist:
        cart = Cart.objects.create(cart_id=_cart_id(request))
        cart.save()
    try:
        cart_item = CartItems.objects.get(product=product, cart=cart)
        cart_item += 1
        cart_item.save()
    except CartItems.DoesNotExist:
        cart_item = CartItems.objects.create(product=product, quantity=1, cart=cart)
        cart_item.save()
    return redirect('cart_app:cart_details')
```

I need `cart_item` incremented by one when an item is added to the cart.

Comment: `cart_item` isn't a number. What would it mean to increment it by one?

Comment: @khelwood, thanks. It worked. I removed that line from my code.

Comment: What are you trying to do with `cart_item += 1`? Does just removing this line really solve the problem? Sure it removes the error, but does the code do what you want?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I am working on a shopping site, just halfway. I think I should consider reworking it.

Comment: @Amalhuda that doesn't answer my question. What do you expect `cart_item += 1` to do?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice it was to increment the quantity of items.

Comment: @Amalhuda Then you need to increment the quantity field as shown by Alex Hall, not the cart item itself. Notice how the English words you use to describe the solution is almost exactly what you need to do in the code. This happens a lot. Pay close attention to the words you use to describe what you are doing and you will often be able to solve many of your coding problems. This is general advice, not just specific for solving this particular problem.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes.thank you for your valuable assistance

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
cart_item += 1
```

with:

```
cart_item.quantity += 1
```